# The onKeyPress event doesn't fire in Chrome on Android?

Tags: android, google-chrome, events, onkeypress

The *onKeyPress* event doesn't fire in Chrome on Android

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I didn't manage to reproduce the issue in Chrome on iOS(v13). As for Android, I reproduced it in the latest Chrome version on Android 9. It occurs because onKeyPress doesn't fire.